# Laravel scss compiling fails

Tags: laravel, sass

I'm trying to learn laravel and set up a new project with composer on Windows 10

if I try to compile the

resources\assets\sass\app.scss

I got the following error

```
Compilation Error
Error: File "c:\Users\Michael\www\demolaravel\resources\assets\sass\node_modules\bootstrap-sass\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap" not found
on line 9 of sass/c:\Users\Michael\www\demolaravel\resources\assets\sass\app.scss
>> @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

why he complains about that dir - also the app.css (at least this particular line) is original. It's the way composer installs it.

```
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600");

// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

body{
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

I just added the body selector at the end 
I work with visual studio code and the live sass compiler extension. But I also tried Scout-App
also tried puting the absolute path but nothing works :(

Comment: Did you install the dependencies using `npm install` on your project?

Comment: No I forgot. Make this an answer and I accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't installed all your node dependencies.

Run this command `npm install` on your project.

the `@import`
write like this

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

compile new css with `npm run dev`

Comment: Sorry I made npm install and it installed a lot of files but if I change my scss now and let it compile I get the same message. :(

Comment: Yes "node_modules\bootstrap-sass" exist

Comment: It seems that elixir is trying to find the file from `sass` folder and appending the path so try this path as from sass directory node_modules is 3 steps backward. `@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

Comment: unfortunately not - same message :(

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: just installed today with composer I think it said 5.4.30

Comment: Ok and are you using `laravel-mix` or `laravel-elixir`? Check your package.json file for this and version number.

Comment: in the packsge.json is "laravel-mix": "^1.0" and no laravel-elixir.

Comment: Hi Zayn I accept and wrote our solution from chat in your answer please check it and correct if needed - thank you

Comment: Hi Zayn just one thing why those ../../../ this is my home (C:\Users\Michael) why do this actually work?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have installed `node` and `npm` globally. Then delete the `node_modules` directory from you project, and run

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

This command may take some times to execute. After that go to your project directory and run `npm install`. Then compile your assets with `laravel-mix`.

I also faced the the same problem in **linux** environment and I have come across with this solution.

Comment: you are also right now it works with the live sass compiler extension from Visual studio Code. But only if I jump three dirs up in my `@import` like 

`@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";` Thank you