# Compiling Sass or Scss Error in Laravel 7 with TailwindCSS

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-7, tailwind-css

I have put the SCSS file in the directory: `ProjectName/public/css/main.scss`

and I have followed the method of this problem but it didn't work, even though it was only a little different, it didn't solve my problem. following the link:[laravel-scss-compiling-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651702/laravel-scss-compiling-fails)

actually I am in this project using `laravel/ui`, that is `Tailwindcss`.

please help with my problem, and hopefully with this it can help friends who are also experiencing problems like me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upiCf.png)

```
Compiling Sass/Scss Files: 
d:\laragon\www\ProjectName\public\css\main.scss
d:\laragon\www\ProjectName\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\bootstrap-stubs\app.scss
--------------------
Compilation Error
Error: File "d:\laragon\www\ProjectName\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\bootstrap-stubs\~bootstrap\scss\bootstrap" not found
        on line 8 of sass/d:\laragon\www\ProjectName\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\bootstrap-stubs\app.scss
>> @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

   --------^

--------------------
```

Comment: `ProjectName/public/css/main.scss` it should be `ProjectName/resources/css/main.scss` then it will be compiled into `ProjectName/public/css/main.css`

Comment: At first glance, there is the issue mentioned above about scss not being the correct place which is an indicator of an incorrect setup. Take a look at the ecosystem here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#introduction